# AJAX code not working on button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am using AJAX for the first time and I'm watching this tutorial so I can implement the feature on my website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLOMd5Ib69Y. What I'm trying to do is make a contact us form where the user can write a message and when he click a button the message is sent to my email. With AJAX I'm trying to change the button content without reloading.

I have this AJAX code:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    var ajax = 
    {
        send: function()
        {
            var userName = $("input[name=un]").val();
            var userEmail = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var userMsg = $("input[name=msg]").val();


        if(userName == "" || userEmail == "" || userMsg == "")
        {
            alert("All fields are required!");
        }
        else
        {
            ajax.SetText("Sending...");
            $.post("sendMSG.php", {

                name : userName, email : userEmail, message : userMsg
            }, function(data){

                ajax.SetText(data);
            });

        }

        },
        SetText: function(text)
        {
            $("input[type=button]").val(text);
        }


    }


</script>
```

And the html form:

```
Name: <br> <input type="text" size="40" name="un">
                    <br>
                    Email: <br> <input type="text" size="40" name="email"> 
                    <br>

                    Write us a Message!
                    <br>    
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="msg" id="content"></textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" value="Send Message!" onClick="ajax.send()" />
```

For some reason when I click on the button nothings happens. As I said this is my first time using AJAX and I don't have idea how to use AJAX code. So please take it easy on me if the answer is simple :p

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the console (press F12) for errors?

Comment: do you know that you are using a very old version of jQuery?

Comment: are you using jqueryu

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks you answer helped me solve my problem. It had a problem reading the jquery-1.4.3.min.js and I used another now and it worked thanks!

Comment: @user3719759 no problem, glad to help. First rule of debugging javascript; check the console.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a rather old version of jQuery. You should use the latest one which can be found on the [**`jQuery Website.`**](http://www.jquery.com)

Now for this example we'll use the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event listener.
First you need to set up a form correctly:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    Name: <br> <input type="text" size="40" name="un">
<br />
    Email: <br> <input type="text" size="40" name="email"> 
<br />
    Write us a Message!
<br />    
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="msg" id="content"></textarea>
<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message!"/>
</form>
```

Now for the jQuery (*as stated above; we'll be using the `submit` event.*) But first we have to ensure the DOM element is loaded before running our jQuery. That is done by using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Setting up our jquery is as simple as writing what we want to do in our `submit` event listener:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('sendMSG.php',{name: userName, email: userEmail, message: userMsg}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    });

});
```

Obviously doing all the proccessing you require before running the `$.post` ajax request.

**A Few Notes:**

- You could use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` within your event to stop the default actions taking place. (*see below*)

`e.PreventDefault()`

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do ajax and processing stuff
});
```

`return false;`

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    // do ajax and processing stuff
    return false;
});
```

- You should look into using [**`jQuery.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of the `jQuery.post` as it gives you more options.

Comment: @user3719759 no worries mate, did it answer your question? Do you have any more questions? :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using `jquery`,So you should put each code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: The ready event is not a panacea to all things that go wrong when using jQuery. Nothing in the code tries to access DOM elements before they exist.